# rtmp stream to png using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am looking for a solution to convert live rtmp stream from FMS/AMS server converted to png/jpeg image stream over http @5fps . Is it possible . Can someone suggest a reliable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this

```sh
#!/bin/sh

foo=(
  'rtmp://server.com/app'
  'playpath=mp4:foo.mp4'
  'swfUrl=http://bar.com/baz.swf'
  'live=1'
)

ffmpeg -i "${foo[*]}" -r 1 a%d.png &

while sleep 1
do
  ls -I a.png | xargs -I % mv % a.png
done
```

ffmpeg will output a numeric png every second (`a1.png` `a2.png` `a3.png`). Then Bash will copy newest one to `a.png` and remove the rest, every second. This will give you a constantly updating `a.png`.